# Use of uninitialized value in pattern match

Tags: regex, perl, initialization

I have the following code in a subroutine in Perl for which I keep getting the following error :
Use of uninitialized value $nextLine in pattern match (m//) at catlist.pl line 67,  line 2756.

```
sub extract_testdesc {
    my @str      = @_;
    my $file     = $_[0];
    my $testname = $_[1];
    my @fifo;

    # Open the file
    open( FILEHANDLE, $file ) or die "couldnt open";
    while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
        if ( $_ =~ m/\/\*\*/ ) {    # if start of comment /**
            undef(@fifo);
            $nextLine = <FILEHANDLE>;
            while ( $nextLine !~ m/\*\// ) {    # Add all lines into array until */ is encountered
                if ( $nextLine !~ m/\@testlogic.author/ ) {
                    $nextLine =~ s/\*//g;
                    if ( $nextLine ne "" ) {
                        push( @fifo, $nextLine );
                    }
                }
                $nextLine = <FILEHANDLE>;
            }
        }

        if ( $_ =~ m/$testname/ ) {
            return (@fifo);
        }
    }
    close(FILEHANDLE);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I'm new to Perl so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you wanna do with that file in the subroutine?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a while loop on a file handle, it's actually synonymous with `while (defined($_ = <FILEHANDLE>)) {`.  This is useful because once the filehandle reaches the [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html), it will exit the loop.  On the other hand, you are doing manual calls [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) calls without testing to see if anything was returned, hence your uninitialized value warnings.

Overall, your goal and logic are confusing.  However, perhaps an introduction to the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) will help you?  The following achieves what I think you logic is, but I easily could have misinterpreted.

```
sub extract_testdesc {
    my ($file, $testname) = @_;

    my @fifo;

    # Open the file
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "couldnt open: $!";
    while (<$fh>) {
        if ( my $range = m{\Q/**} .. m{\Q*/}) {
            @fifo = () if $range == 1;
            push @fifo, $_;

        } elsif ($_ =~ m/\Q$testname\E/ ) {
            return (@fifo);
        }
    }
    close($fh);
}
```